# Editing file using SHA - git

Tags: git, sha

My question is perhaps very basic, but how do I edit a specific file from a version commit (whose author is a colleague working on the same remote repo as me) from which I know the SHA ?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit" ? Do you want to retrieve this file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to get the content of the file, you can do

```
 git show someHash:pathToFile
```

If you want to see the differences between current version of the file with the one of the commit, you may do

```
 git diff someHash pathToFile
```

If you want to replace current version of the file with the one of the commit, you may do

```
 git reset --hard someHash pathToFile
```

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout hashOfCommit path/to/file`

You can then edit the file and commit your changes to the branch you are on currently.

Comment: it is better to type `git checkout hashOfCommit -- path/to/file`